Unable to execute script. Reports there's no open Revit Project
I'm creating a python script to run in the RevitPythonShell 2024.0.0.0 add-in for Revit which will look for duplicate Family/Type names of elements housed in differing Revit Worksets, perform a renaming function and report the results. It's unable to as the script is unable to verify that a Revit Project is actually open to perform any of the tasks (though one clearly is: Workshared Revit model with over 16,000 Revit elements) Provides the following error:

No document is currently open or the document is disposed

and aborts.
Below is the logic path and current script:
Logic Path:
Step 1: References the Revit API and checks if a project is open. Displays a confirmation dialog.
Step 2: Compiles a list of families and their types by workset.
Step 3: Compares the families and their types from each workset.
Step 4: Identifies duplicates and displays them in a dialog box.
Step 5: Renames duplicate families by appending the workset name to the family name.
Step 6: Displays success or failure messages based on the renaming process.
Step 7: Writes a report to the specified path.
Script below:
import clr
import os
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
clr.AddReference('System')

from Autodesk.Revit.DB import FilteredElementCollector, BuiltInParameter, Family, Transaction
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import TaskDialog, TaskDialogCommonButtons, TaskDialogResult
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

def main():
    doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

    # Check if the document is valid
    if doc is None or doc.IsDisposed:
        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "No document is currently open or the document is disposed.")
        return
    
    filename = doc.PathName
    if filename == "":
        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "No document is currently open.")
        return

    result = TaskDialog.Show("Confirm", f"Current Project: {filename}\n\nDo you want to proceed?", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Yes | TaskDialogCommonButtons.No)
    if result == TaskDialogResult.No:
        return

    # Create a dictionary to store families and their types by workset
    workset_dict = {}

    # Create a list to store the report data
    report_data = []

    # Get all families in the document
    collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)

    for family in collector:
        # Get the workset of the family
        workset_param = family.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ELEM_PARTITION_PARAM)
        if workset_param:
            workset_name = workset_param.AsValueString()

            # Initialize the workset dictionary if not already
            if workset_name not in workset_dict:
                workset_dict[workset_name] = {}

            # Get all types of the family
            symbols = family.GetFamilySymbolIds()
            for symbol_id in symbols:
                symbol = doc.GetElement(symbol_id)
                family_name = family.Name
                type_name = symbol.Name

                # Store family and type in the dictionary
                if family_name not in workset_dict[workset_name]:
                    workset_dict[workset_name][family_name] = []
                workset_dict[workset_name][family_name].append(type_name)

    # Find duplicates
    duplicates = {}
    for workset_name, families in workset_dict.items():
        for family_name, types in families.items():
            for other_workset_name, other_families in workset_dict.items():
                if workset_name != other_workset_name and family_name in other_families:
                    if family_name not in duplicates:
                        duplicates[family_name] = {}
                    if workset_name not in duplicates[family_name]:
                        duplicates[family_name][workset_name] = []
                    if other_workset_name not in duplicates[family_name]:
                        duplicates[family_name][other_workset_name] = []
                    duplicates[family_name][workset_name] = types
                    duplicates[family_name][other_workset_name] = workset_dict[other_workset_name][family_name]

    if not duplicates:
        TaskDialog.Show("Info", "No duplicate families found.")
        return

    duplicate_list = ""
    for family_name, worksets in duplicates.items():
        duplicate_list += f"Family: {family_name}\n"
        for workset_name, types in worksets.items():
            type_list = ", ".join(types)
            duplicate_list += f"  Workset: {workset_name}, Types: {type_list}\n"
    result = TaskDialog.Show("Duplicates Found", f"Duplicate Families and Types:\n{duplicate_list}\n\nDo you want to proceed?", TaskDialogCommonButtons.Yes | TaskDialogCommonButtons.No)
    if result == TaskDialogResult.No:
        return

    # Rename duplicates
    rename_success = True
    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)
    try:
        for family_name, worksets in duplicates.items():
            for workset_name in worksets:
                for family in FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family):
                    if family.Name == family_name:
                        new_family_name = f"{workset_name}_{family_name}"
                        family.Name = new_family_name
                        report_data.append([workset_name, family_name, new_family_name])
        TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
    except Exception as e:
        TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
        rename_success = False
        TaskDialog.Show("Error", str(e))

    if rename_success:
        TaskDialog.Show("Success", "Success!")
    else:
        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "Unable to complete task.")
        return

    # Write report
    username = os.getlogin()
    report_path = fr"C:\Users\{username}\Desktop\TWT\Duplicate_Family_Rename_Report.txt"

    with open(report_path, 'w') as report_file:
        report_file.write("Workset,Original Name,New Name\n")
        for data in report_data:
            report_file.write(f"{data[0]},{data[1]},{data[2]}\n")

    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", f"Report saved to: {report_path}")

main()

I also tried replacing the front end code with code from another version which performed a much simpler renaming task (not fully what I wanted, hence the enhanced version above) and was originally successful.
Script Front End Replace (entire new script included):
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager**

# Get the current Revit document
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

# Check if the document is valid
doc_status_message = "Document is None or Disposed"
if doc is not None and not doc.IsDisposed:
    doc_status_message = f"Document Title: {doc.Title}"

# Show a message box with the document status
TaskDialog.Show("Debug Info", doc_status_message)

# Proceed only if the document is valid
if doc is None or doc.IsDisposed:
    TaskDialog.Show("Error", "No document is currently open or the document is disposed.")
else:
    # Create a dictionary to store families and types by workset
    workset_dict = {}

    # Create a list to store the report data
    report_data = []

    # Get all families in the document
    collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)

    for family in collector:
        # Get the workset of the family
        workset_param = family.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ELEM_PARTITION_PARAM)
        if workset_param:
            workset_name = workset_param.AsValueString()

            # Initialize the workset dictionary if not already
            if workset_name not in workset_dict:
                workset_dict[workset_name] = {}

            # Get all types of the family
            symbols = family.GetFamilySymbolIds()
            for symbol_id in symbols:
                symbol = doc.GetElement(symbol_id)
                family_name = family.Name
                type_name = symbol.Name

                # Store family and type in the dictionary
                if family_name not in workset_dict[workset_name]:
                    workset_dict[workset_name][family_name] = []
                workset_dict[workset_name][family_name].append(type_name)

    # Function to rename families and types
    def rename_family_and_types(family, new_family_name, doc, workset_name, original_name):
        t = Transaction(doc, "Rename Family and Types")
        t.Start()
        try:
            family.Name = new_family_name
            symbols = family.GetFamilySymbolIds()
            for symbol_id in symbols:
                symbol = doc.GetElement(symbol_id)
                symbol.Name = new_family_name + "_" + symbol.Name
            t.Commit()
            # Add to the report data
            report_data.append([workset_name, original_name, new_family_name])
        except Exception as e:
            t.RollBack()
            TaskDialog.Show("Error", str(e))

    # Iterate over the workset dictionary to check for duplicate names
    for workset_name, families in workset_dict.items():
        for family_name, types in families.items():
            for other_workset_name, other_families in workset_dict.items():
                if workset_name != other_workset_name and family_name in other_families:
                    # Rename the family and types with workset prefix
                    collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)
                    for family in collector:
                        if family.Name == family_name:
                            new_family_name = f"{workset_name}_{family_name}"
                            rename_family_and_types(family, new_family_name, doc, workset_name, family_name)

    # Specify the report file path
    report_path = r"C:\Users\nwakeman\OneDrive - Wade Trim\Desktop\TWT\Family_Rename_Report.txt"

    # Create the report file
    with open(report_path, 'w') as report_file:
        report_file.write("Workset\tOriginal Name\tNew Name\n")
        for data in report_data:
            report_file.write(f"{data[0]}\t{data[1]}\t{data[2]}\n")

    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", f"Renaming of Families and Types based on Worksets is complete.\nReport saved to: {report_path}")`

Original Script that did acknowledge the same open Revit Project - for reference:
`import clr
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
clr.AddReference("RevitAPIUI")

from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

import os

# Get the current document
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

# Create a dictionary to store families and types by workset
workset_dict = {}

# Create a list to store the report data
report_data = []

# Get all families in the document
collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)

for family in collector:
    # Get the workset of the family
    workset_param = family.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.ELEM_PARTITION_PARAM)
    if workset_param:
        workset_name = workset_param.AsValueString()
        
        # Initialize the workset dictionary if not already
        if workset_name not in workset_dict:
            workset_dict[workset_name] = {}
        
        # Get all types of the family
        symbols = family.GetFamilySymbolIds()
        for symbol_id in symbols:
            symbol = doc.GetElement(symbol_id)
            family_name = family.Name
            type_name = symbol.Name
            
            # Store family and type in the dictionary
            if family_name not in workset_dict[workset_name]:
                workset_dict[workset_name][family_name] = []
            workset_dict[workset_name][family_name].append(type_name)

# Function to rename families and types
def rename_family_and_types(family, new_family_name, doc, workset_name, original_name):
    TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)
    family.Name = new_family_name
    symbols = family.GetFamilySymbolIds()
    for symbol_id in symbols:
        symbol = doc.GetElement(symbol_id)
        symbol.Name = new_family_name + "_" + symbol.Name
    TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()
    # Add to the report data
    report_data.append([workset_name, original_name, new_family_name])

# Iterate over the workset dictionary to check for duplicate names
for workset_name, families in workset_dict.items():
    for family_name, types in families.items():
        for other_workset_name, other_families in workset_dict.items():
            if workset_name != other_workset_name and family_name in other_families:
                # Rename the family and types with workset prefix
                collector = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Family)
                for family in collector:
                    if family.Name == family_name:
                        new_family_name = f"{workset_name}_{family_name}"
                        rename_family_and_types(family, new_family_name, doc, workset_name, family_name)

# Specify the report file path
report_path = r"C:\Users\nwakeman\OneDrive - Wade Trim\Desktop\TWT\Family_Rename_Report.txt"

# Create the report file
with open(report_path, 'w') as report_file:
    report_file.write("Workset\tOriginal Name\tNew Name\n")
    for data in report_data:
        report_file.write(f"{data[0]}\t{data[1]}\t{data[2]}\n")

TaskDialog.Show("Revit", f"Renaming of Families and Types based on Worksets is complete.\nReport saved to: {report_path}")


Callum,
Thank you! We are attempting Revit automation for the purposes of standardizing Family Naming in preparation for Digital Twin creation. Duplicate Family names after merging Revit models from differing disciplines can pose a challenge... Hence the script idea.
I’m boarding a plane at the moment yet want to reply to your kind response.
I’ll start by admitting not being a coder myself and attempted to use ChatGPT to assist with generating the actual code. Not being a coder, I had little to go by on the code it generated where verification is concerned, even though I threw the errors back at it. This is surely why there are errant definitions.
FYI - Here’s my original prompt and a subsequent clarification before it’s generating of the script that I originally shared.
ChatGPT prompt:
You are an expert in Revit, the Revit API, and IronPython. I am a novice in all three of those. I need you to create a Python Script in IronPython format and compatible with the IronPythonShell add-in for Revit that performs the following steps:

Reference the Revit Project already open in Revit at the time
1a. Verify that there is a Revit Project open by displaying the filename in a dialog box and provide a Button to proceed in the same dialog box to continue running the script. If you can't verify a Revit Project is already open, provide a dialog box describing such and a button to abort running the script in the same dialog box
If you were able to verify an open Revit Project and the user clicked on the Proceed buttong, Compile a list of all Revit Families and Types from the open Revit Project separated by the workset in which they belong
Compare the Revit Family and Type Names from each Workset
If duplicate Revit Family and Type Names exist between worksets, provide a dialog box listing the duplicates beside each other in alphanumeric order along with the workset name to which each belong and also provide Dialog Buttons to Proceed in the same dialog box.
If no duplicates are found, provide a Cancel Button in the same dialog box to abort running the script
If the user clicks the Proceed button and duplicate Revit Family and Type Names exist between worksets, rename both Family Names only appending the Workset Name to the front of the Revit Family Name, leaving the Type unchanged
If successful, provide a dialog box displaying the word "Success!" and an "OK" button to continue, otherwise, display "Unable to complete task" in the same dialog box along with a Cancel button to abort running the script
If the user clicks OK in the dialog above, write a text file report  in CSV format of the final result in the same form as in the successful dialog above and to the following path and filename C:\users%username%\desktop\TWT\Duplicate_Family_Rename_Report.txt

Acknowledge that you understand all instructions completely and ask permission to proceed with creating the python script or, if you don't understand completely ask questions prior.
My prompt clarifications after ChatGPT’s acknowledgement of understanding and initial response:
Clarify step #2 to Compile a list of all Revit Families and their related Types separated by workset.
Clarify step #3 to Compare the Revit Family and their related Types from each Workset.
Clarify step #4 to Identify and list duplicate Families and related Type names between worksets.
End of Prompt:

Callum,
I will modify the script with your corrections and thank you again for the needed/actual verification to troubleshoot.

awesome idea for a script.
Where did you get those initial definitions from? I havent heard of RevitServices.Persistence or RevitServices.Transactions before - they sound really interesting.
I can get your sript running if I use a common set of initial definitions:
import clr
import os
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')

from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import *

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

Now doc works as desired
There are a few other bugs I came across though:
symbol.Name needs to be Element.Name.__get__(symbol) (strangely, family.Name works fine though - something to do Python mapping to Net)
Let us know how you get on!

I revised the initial definitions to your corrections.
I also attempted to rework the symbol.Name portion you suggested. I'm sure I messed that up. Can you post your actual code for that entire section, or perhaps your entire script that worked?
